# Asp.net web form to connect office 365 outlook

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, outlook, office365

i am creating asp.net simple web App my recommendation is when iam click to button it will connect to office 365 outlook and also login with api programmatically is there any way to perform this operation please guide me.

Comment: Put more effort in asking question.  Have you done some R&D put the links. If you have tried some code put that also in you question. Here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) providing details about how to ask a good question.

Comment: You could try this steps as per [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0)